# How to stop editor removing space (&nbsp;) in the beginning of the paragraph

Tags: tinymce

I use WordPress with TinyMCE in Chinese.

It needs double white spaces in the beginning of each paragraph. But the editor will automatically removing all spaces(white space and `nbsp;` code) in the beginning of the paragraph when I toggle the editor between WYSIWYG mode and HTML mode.

When I used WordPress 3.8, I could stop it doing this with these code

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'preserve_nbsp_chars');
function preserve_nbsp_chars($initArray) {
    $initArray['entities'] = $initArray['entities'].',160,nbsp';
    return $initArray;
}
```

The bad thing is it does not work after I updated WP to 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

An ugly workaround I have always used in WordPress to add spaces is use `<b>&nbsp;</b>`

It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: Thank you very much!You're right.But I still want to find some way to keep spaces without using html code.

Answer (score 4):

```
//[nbsp] shortcode
function nbsp_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
$content = '&nbsp';
return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'nbsp', 'nbsp_shortcode' );
```

Then call it like this:

[nbsp]

Instead of:

```
&nbsp;
```

Hat tip to this post on wordpress.org: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-nbsp-characters-from-getting-removed-by-the-visual-editor

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, welcome to WPSE and thanks for your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged as they can change over time. You can use the link to provide context, but could you edit your answer to include the relevant information & code for the `[nbsp]` workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Sure I just didn't want to plagiarise their information, and I doubt wordpress org's url will change, but will do no worries.